# Notice: Undefined index: identifier não acho o erro

Tags: php, wordpress

Está dando esse erro em várias parte da minha *homepage*. Mas não sei como resolver. Segue o erro e a linha de código correspondente.

```
Notice: Undefined index: identifier in /home3/.../helpers-general.php on line 1112
```

Parte do código que contém a linha 1112:

```
function foodbakery_set_transient_obj($transient_variable, $data_string, $time = 12) {
    if ( !isset($_COOKIE['identifier']) || $_COOKIE['identifier'] == '' ) {
        setcookie('identifier', uniqid(), time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
    }
    $result = '';
    $identifier = '';
    $identifier = $_COOKIE['identifier'];  // <==== linha 1112
    $time_string = $time * HOUR_IN_SECONDS;
    if ( $data_string != '' ) {
        $result = set_transient($identifier . $transient_variable, $data_string, $time_string);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que o erro está na má interpretação do protocolo HTTP.

O que a função `setcookie` faz é definir um cabeçalho de resposta `Set-Cookie` na resposta HTTP que será enviado ao cliente; enquanto `$_COOKIE` é uma lista de *cookies* existentes na requisição corrente. Em outras palavras, `setcookie` **não altera o valor de `$_COOKIE` da própria requisição**.

A [própria documentação oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php) diz isso:

> Uma vez que os cookies foram setados, eles podem ser acessados **no próximo carregamento da página** através do array `$_COOKIE`.

O erro então acontece quando a requisição atual não possui o *cookie* `identifier`. Você definirá o valor dele, mas esse valor existirá somente a partir da próxima requisição.

Busque entender a diferença entre os cabeçalhos `Set-Cookie` e `Cookie`.

O que você pode fazer é algo como:

```
$identifier = $_COOKIE['identifier'] ?? null;
// Versões anteriores à 7:
// $identifier = isset($_COOKIE['identifier']) ? $_COOKIE['identifier'] : null;

if (is_null($identifier)) {
    $identifier = uniqid();
    setcookie('identifier', $identifier, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
}

// Use $identifier
```

Comment: Já tem algo parecido logo abaixo..
`if ( ! function_exists('foodbakery_get_transient_obj') ) {

    function foodbakery_get_transient_obj($transient_variable) {
        //$data_string = get_transient( $transient_variable );
        $identifier = uniqid();
        if ( isset($_COOKIE['identifier']) ) {
            $identifier = $_COOKIE['identifier'];
        }
        if ( false === ( $data_string = get_transient($identifier . $transient_variable) ) ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return $data_string;
        }
    }

}`

Comment: @MauricioSantos Então, com isso, posso assumir que você entendeu o que está errado e conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: Então, Anderson, esse código já estava lá, não inclui nada. Ainda não entendi o motivo do erro, pois quando entro com o usuário adm o erro não aparece. Mas em outras contas ou computadores o erro continua aparecendo;

Comment: Mas ele "estava lá" em uma função completamente diferente da que você colocou na pergunta. O erro está na função `foodbakery_set_transient_obj` e essa lógica só foi utilizada na `foodbakery_get_transient_obj`. Você leu a resposta por completo? Pesquisou a respeito dos cabeçalhos HTTP citados? O que não entendeu?

Comment: Entendi, não tem nada a ver uma função com a outra. Eu não entendi exatamente o motivo do erro porque não sei PHP, então basicamente não sei o que está acontecendo ali. Mas por algum motivo o erro parou de aparecer. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @MauricioSantos Mas o erro não é do PHP, é de HTTP. PHP, neste caso, foi só a ferramenta para gerenciar o HTTP. Se está trabalhando com web e não tem ideia do que eu falei na resposta, recomendo fortemente que pare tudo e estude o protocolo HTTP.

Comment: Entendi, vou fazer isso. Obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score -2):

Tente assim:

```
function foodbakery_set_transient_obj($transient_variable, $data_string, $time = 12) {
if ( !isset($_COOKIE['identifier']) || $_COOKIE['identifier'] == '' ) {
    setcookie('identifier', uniqid(), time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
}
$result = '';
$identifier = isset($_COOKIE['identifier'])?isset($_COOKIE['identifier']):'';  // <==== linha 1112
$time_string = $time * HOUR_IN_SECONDS;
if ( $data_string != '' ) {
    $result = set_transient($identifier . $transient_variable, $data_string, $time_string);
}
return $result;
```

}

Comment: Neste caso omitiria a mensagem de erro, mas o valor de `$identifier` ficaria uma string vazia quando o *cookie* não existir, o que não parece fazer muito sentido.

Comment: Essa é só uma forma de desviar do Notice, não causará efeito no código. Obviamente ele deve tratar o motivo pelo qual o `identifier` está vazio (por exemplo, cookies desabilitados)

Comment: Mas o problema não é cookies desabilitados, mas sim querer definir e usar um cookie na mesma requisição. O HTTP não funciona assim.

Comment: A pergunta é sobre o notice. O notice avisa que esta mostrando uma variável que pode não ter sido inicializada. Não é erro, apenas aviso de má-prática de programação.

No caso, em modo algum a variável deixaria de ser iniciada, já que no "if" ele seta o cookie usando a função setcookie. Porém o php não sabe disso e marca como variável não inicializada. A não ser que faça uma verificação como a que citei.

Comment: Tem uma série de equívocos que talvez possam ser resolvidos com uma edição. O que a resposta atual (se consertado o segundo isset da linha 1112) fará é mascarar o erro, escondendo o notice, mas ainda trabalhando com valores errados. Vide a resposta aceita para uma solução real do problema. PS: Note o uso do ?? na resposta, que pode ser substituido pelo isset em versões mais antigas do PHP.